# Create unique id on browser tab to keep content of page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, session-storage

I'm generating unique id by

```
session_start();
$id = session_id();
```

then I'm saving content of web app in database, where primary key is equal to **$id**. I'm doing this to keep the content of page after refresh.
But when I open another tab, content of both pages is equal.
I red about **sessionStorage** but I need to generate specific id only when tab is opened for the first time and avoid this behaviour after refresh.
I would love to solve this problem via JavaScript or HTML5 because PHP is running on server side.

Comment: that's because sessions (by default) use cookies, and cookies are shared between all tabs in a browser instance. that means every tab will have the same session cookie, and therefore the same ID. you'd need to open tables in porn *ahem* private/icognito mode so they don't share cookies, or not use sessions for this.

Comment: if you need a unique id for dynamically created elements on the browser, you can use JavaScript Date object and getTime() method http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Comment: @jyrkim I like this getTime() idea, I'll combine it with sessionStorage, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your each page has different/unique url you can get that url at `php` side `md5()`-it and save to db your data with that unique key

```
$current_page_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$yourPageReleventUniqueId = md5($current_page_link); // string
```

documentation for `md5` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to implement some kind of caching.

Rather than store the page output using the session_id as a key, you could use the route e.g. '/foo'.  Or a combination of session_id and route.